# Limit of this definite integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How can I compute this integral for $y\rightarrow0$ ?

$$ \int_0^1{\frac{y(1-x)^2(1+x)}{x+(1-x^2)y} dx} $$

Comment: Did you really mean to ask this here since you also posted on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3209353/limit-of-this-definite-real-integral)?

Comment: Am I missing something? The integrand clearly goes to 0 as y approaches zero.

Comment: @infinitezero It seems there are some doubts about order of limits in `y->0` and `x` close to zero. Doing `x` integral first and then taking `y->0` does give the expected zero of course.

Answer (score 2):

```
Assuming[y > 0, 
  AsymptoticIntegrate[(y (1 - x)^2 (1 + x))/(x + (1 - x^2) y), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]]
```

> 1/6 y (-7 - 6 Log[y])

So the limit for $y\to0^+$ is zero:

```
Limit[%, y -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]
```

> 0

For $y<0$ the integral does not converge.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the same result but analytically?

Comment: `Integrate[(y (1 - x)^2 (1 + x))/(x + (1 - x^2) y), {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> y > 0]` maybe, although the above is already analytic.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach if you want to avoid the use of `AsymptoticIntegrate` (whose very presence I learnt today, thanks @Roman:-)!).

```
Timing[
 FullSimplify[
  Integrate[(y (1 - x)^2 (1 + x))/(x + (1 - x^2) y), {x, 0, 1}, 
   Assumptions -> y > 0], y > 0]]
(* {6.64063, ((-2 + y) y Sqrt[1 + 4 y^2] - (-1 + y) Sqrt[
   1 + 4 y^2]
    Log[y] + (1 - 2 y) y Log[(1 + 2 y - Sqrt[1 + 4 y^2])/(
    1 + 2 y + Sqrt[1 + 4 y^2])] + 
  Log[(1 + 2 y + Sqrt[1 + 4 y^2])/(1 + 2 y - Sqrt[1 + 4 y^2])])/(
 2 y^2 Sqrt[1 + 4 y^2])} *)

Normal[
  Series[(1/(
   2 y^2 Sqrt[
    1 + 4 y^2]))((-2 + y) y Sqrt[1 + 4 y^2] - (-1 + y) Sqrt[1 + 4 y^2]
       Log[y] + (1 - 2 y) y Log[(1 + 2 y - Sqrt[1 + 4 y^2])/(
       1 + 2 y + Sqrt[1 + 4 y^2])] + 
     Log[(1 + 2 y + Sqrt[1 + 4 y^2])/(
      1 + 2 y - Sqrt[1 + 4 y^2])]), {y, 0, 1}]] // 
 FullSimplify[#, y > 0] &
(* -(1/6) y (7 + 6 Log[y]) *)
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP asked whether there is a way to achieve the result "analytically", which I assume implies "by steps that can be considered a proof by humans". Here is an attempt.

Define integrand

```
integrand = (y (1 - x)^2 (1 + x))/(x + (1 - x^2) y);
```

For any `y>0` we see that there is no pole on the interval `1>x>0`, which means we can obtain the integral over this region using the fundamental theorem of calculus by taking a difference of anti-derivatives evaluated at the boundary points.

First we may "guess" an anti-derivative:

```
antiderivative = Assuming[y > 0, Integrate[integrand, x] // Simplify]
```

> [image]

to prove that this is in fact a valid anti-derivative, simply take the derivative which is a simple mechanical process and can be done either by hand or as:

```
D[antiderivative, x] - integrand // Simplify
```

> 0

Having proven that we in fact have a correct anti-derivative, we evaluate it at the boundary points and take a difference:

```
integral = (antiderivative /. x -> 1) - (antiderivative /. x -> 0) // FullSimplify
```

> [image]

Finally, we take a series expansion of this result around the point `y=0` to figure out its leading behavior:

```
Assuming[y > 0, Series[integral, {y, 0, 0}]]
```

> [image]

This means that the integral result vanishes at least linearly in `y->0` so that the integral is zero in that limit.

Note that the derivative to prove the anti-derivative, the evaluation at `x=1` and `x=0`, and the Taylor expansion around `y=0` all can be done by hand on a piece of paper, which makes the steps humanly traceable and therefore constitutes a proof.